# How can I cancel a download from DownloadManager APi on Android?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want the user to be able to press a button to cancel a download, but not remove from the list!

I know the DownloadManager class has a remove method, but this method cancels and removes the download from the list. I want just to cancel the download and not remove the list and the user can then retry the download.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want more of a pause button? Or a restart button?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to cancel the download, call DownloadManager#remove() passing in that long.

```
// Start a download
long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

// Stop a download
downloadManager.remove(id);
```

Comment: according to android doc remove method :
Cancel downloads and remove them from the download manager.
but I want only cancel download not remove

Comment: Remove is method. but it is perform cancel event. don't worry. Please try it.